# Get unique results with Prolog

Tags: prolog, prolog-dif

I have this Prolog code that returns: `[[vincent,vincent],[vincent,marcellus],[marcellus,vincent],[marcellus,marcellus],[pumpkin,pumpkin],[honey_bunny,honey_bunny]]`.

```
:- initialization main.

loves(vincent, mia).
loves(marcellus, mia).
loves(pumpkin, honey_bunny).
loves(honey_bunny, pumpkin).

jealous(X, Y) :-
    loves(X, Z),
    loves(Y, Z).

main :- 
    findall([X, Y], jealous(X, Y), L),
    write(L),
    halt.
```

How to get the only results when X != Y?
I tried the following code to get the same results as before.

```
jealous(X, Y) :-
    X \== Y,
    loves(X, Z),
    loves(Y, Z).
```

With `\=`, I got `[]`.
How to get only `[vincent,marcellus]` as a result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of the goals in your attempted solution is wrong. When called with two distinct variables, the `(\==)/2` standard predicate always succeed. The solution is to call the predicate only when its arguments are instantiated:

```
jealous(X, Y) :-
    loves(X, Z),
    loves(Y, Z),
    X \== Y.
```

With this fix, your query now returns:

```
?- findall([X, Y], jealous(X, Y), L).
L = [[vincent, marcellus], [marcellus, vincent]].
```

So, no one is jealous of himself anymore. But you still get a redundant solution. We can modify the `jealous/2` predicate to *sort* the names in the returned solutions. For example:

```
jealous(X, Y) :-
    loves(X0, Z),
    loves(Y0, Z),
    X0 \== Y0,
    (   X0 @< Y0 ->
        X = X0, Y = Y0
    ;   X = Y0, Y = X0
    ).
```

Now, by using `setof/3` instead of `findall/3`, we get:

```
?- setof([X, Y], jealous(X, Y), L).
L = [[marcellus, vincent]].
```

One final observation. A list is a poor solution for representing a *pair*. The traditional way is to use either `X-Y` or `(X, Y)`.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever possible, use `dif/2` instead of `(\==)/2`.

`dif/2` will help you write logically sound programs.

For details, look at [prolog-dif](/questions/tagged/prolog-dif)!