# Easier way to get "unique" bindings?

Tags: prolog

Sorry if my terminology is off.  Long term (40 years? ouch...) imperative programmer, dabbled in functional, spending some time this morning trying to be a bit more serious about declarative.  Going through a learning site, and decided to try the "crossword" in exercise 2.4 here:  http://www.learnprolognow.org/lpnpage.php?pagetype=html&pageid=lpn-htmlse7

I've got it, but it feels ridiculously clunky.  Here's my newbie solution:

```
word(astante,  a,s,t,a,n,t,e).
word(astoria,  a,s,t,o,r,i,a).
word(baratto,  b,a,r,a,t,t,o).
word(cobalto,  c,o,b,a,l,t,o).
word(pistola,  p,i,s,t,o,l,a).
word(statale,  s,t,a,t,a,l,e).

crossword(V1,V2,V3,H1,H2,H3):-
    word(V1,V1a,V1b,V1c,V1d,V1e,V1f,V1g),
    word(V2,V2a,V2b,V2c,V2d,V2e,V2f,V2g),
    word(V3,V3a,V3b,V3c,V3d,V3e,V3f,V3g),
    word(H1,H1a,H1b,H1c,H1d,H1e,H1f,H1g),
    word(H2,H2a,H2b,H2c,H2d,H2e,H2f,H2g),
    word(H3,H3a,H3b,H3c,H3d,H3e,H3f,H3g),
    V1b = H1b,
    V1d = H2b,
    V1f = H3b,
    V2b = H1d,
    V2d = H2d,
    V2f = H3d,
    V3b = H1f,
    V3d = H2f,
    V3f = H3f,
    not(V1 = V2),
    not(V1 = V3),
    not(V1 = H1),
    not(V1 = H2),
    not(V1 = H3),
    not(V2 = V3),
    not(V2 = H1),
    not(V2 = H2),
    not(V2 = H3),
    not(V3 = H1),
    not(V3 = H2),
    not(V3 = H3),
    not(H1 = H2),
    not(H1 = H3),
    not(H2 = H3).
```

It works.  crossword will give me the two possible layouts (puzzle is symmetric, after all).  But yeesh...

Some of the clunkiness is just because I've only started, so I don't have any feel for how to mark bindings as "don't care" (the 1st, 3rd, 5th, and 7th letters of the words are completely irrelevant, for instance).  But what is really chafing me right now is having to put in the triangular matrix of "don't duplicate any bindings" there at the end.  This issue keeps coming up (an earlier toy problem involved loves(A,B) and jealous(X,Y) and if you allow X=Y then everybody leading off a loves relationship is claimed to be jealous of themselves (which I see someone else was fighting with a few years ago:[Get unique results with Prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28267488/get-unique-results-with-prolog?rq=1))), but this tutorial doesn't address it.  It hasn't even told me about 'not' yet -- I had to dig around elsewhere to get that, which led into completely valid questions of "well, what kind of 'not equal' did you want?", which I am currently unprepared to answer.  But I digress...

It is inconceivable to me that this is the way this actually gets done in real code.  Combinatorially, it's ridiculous.  And it seems like it violates (or at least bends) the principal of least astonishment.  Without the uniqueness restrictions, there are a huge number of solutions that just set V1=H1, V2=H2, V3=H3.  I guess I could have only disallowed those, but the real solution needs to do the full restriction.

Yes, I completely understand that logically and mathematically there is no reason not to bind the same value into multiple parameters, and also that there are many situations where such a multiple binding is not just helpful but required to handle the issues at hand.  I'm not arguing with the default behavior at all, just looking for a better way to express uniqueness constraints when I need them.

I'd love to know a better way to handle this, because honestly I don't think I can dig much deeper into these tutorials if they're all going to require this much fluff to do something so seemingly obvious.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: replace `not(X = Y)` by `dif(X,Y)` and put all those and the `(=)/2`in front. Still clunky, but much more efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But what is really chafing me right now is having to put in the triangular matrix of "don't duplicate any bindings" there at the end.

We can get a better solution with the `all_dif/1` predicate from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47294595/4391743

```
all_dif([]).
all_dif([E|Es]) :-
   maplist(dif(E), Es),
   all_dif(Es).
```

This predicate accepts a list of elements that are all different from each other. Don't worry about not understanding it just yet, you can treat it as a black box for now.

You can use this to replace the big block of `not` goals at the end of your predicate definition:

```
crossword(V1,V2,V3,H1,H2,H3):-
    ... % unchanged code here
    all_dif([V1, V2, V3, H1, H2, H3]).
```

With this you get back to only the two solutions in which all the words are used.

> I don't have any feel for how to mark bindings as "don't care" (the 1st, 3rd, 5th, and 7th letters of the words are completely irrelevant, for instance).

This is indeed a very important issue! And Prolog should warn you about variables you only use once (called "singletons"), because they are a frequent source of bugs:

```
Singleton variables: [V1a,V1c,V1e,V1g,V2a,V2c,V2e,V2g,V3a,V3c,V3e,V3g,H1a,H1c,H1e,H1g,H2a,H2c,H2e,H2g,H3a,H3c,H3e,H3g]
```

You explicitly mark a variable as "don't care" by giving it a name that starts with the underscore character `_`, or just naming it `_` altogether. Different occurrences of `_` mark different "don't care" variables. So we get:

```
crossword(V1,V2,V3,H1,H2,H3):-
    word(V1,_,V1b,_,V1d,_,V1f,_),
    word(V2,_,V2b,_,V2d,_,V2f,_),
    word(V3,_,V3b,_,V3d,_,V3f,_),
    word(H1,_,H1b,_,H1d,_,H1f,_),
    word(H2,_,H2b,_,H2d,_,H2f,_),
    word(H3,_,H3b,_,H3d,_,H3f,_),
    V1b = H1b,
    V1d = H2b,
    V1f = H3b,
    V2b = H1d,
    V2d = H2d,
    V2f = H3d,
    V3b = H1f,
    V3d = H2f,
    V3f = H3f,
    all_dif([V1, V2, V3, H1, H2, H3]).
```

The warnings are gone *and* we the program is easier to read because the underscores leave "holes" in uninteresting places, and we see more clearly which variables matter.

That leaves us with the task of removing all those equations. General Prolog tip: Except maybe sometimes for reasons of clarity, there is never any need to write an equation of the form `Var1 = Var2` where both sides are variables. Just use the same name for both variables in the whole clause, and you get the same result!

So let's replace `V1b` and `H1b` by the same variable named `A`, `V1d` and `H2b` by the same variable `B`, etc.:

```
crossword(V1,V2,V3,H1,H2,H3):-
    word(V1,_,A,_,B,_,C,_),
    word(V2,_,D,_,E,_,F,_),
    word(V3,_,G,_,H,_,I,_),
    word(H1,_,A,_,D,_,G,_),
    word(H2,_,B,_,E,_,H,_),
    word(H3,_,C,_,F,_,I,_),
    all_dif([V1, V2, V3, H1, H2, H3]).
```

This is equivalent to your initial solution and, I hope, fairly beginner-friendly.

Hopefully this convices you that Prolog programs can be a bit less clunky than your first attempt. Please stick around, we're here to help if you get stuck, and hopefully you will have some less frustrating experiences and see the magic of Prolog.

Comment: Thank you, both for the all_dif (to save my sanity until the tutorials get around to their explanation) and for pointing out that all of the = predicates were unnecessary.  When I saw that, and thought of the context of the exercise, I realized that that was exactly what they were trying to get across -- they had explicitly pointed out that using the same variable in multiple predicates saved effort for you and for Prolog.  Also thank you for explaining the _ variables, which they have mentioned as being a valid token, but hadn't yet explained the significance of their handling.

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, the exercise is **setting you up for failure**.

First, because it uses a knowledge representation that is *unsuitable* for processing similar elements in a uniform fashion.

Second, because you do not have the necessary prerequisites at this point in the book to do so, even if the knowledge representation would make it easier.

I can assure you: What you are doing is of course *not* necessary when programming in Prolog.

So, don't let a single book detract you from the language.

At this point, I would like to show you how you *could* solve this task if you had more experience with the language, and used more suitable language features. You may enjoy going back to this later, when you have read other material.

The key change I would like to make is to let you reason about the available words more explicitly, as data structures that are available *within* your program, instead of "only" as facts:

```
words(Ws) :-
        Ws = [[a,s,t,a,n,t,e],
              [a,s,t,o,r,i,a],
              [b,a,r,a,t,t,o],
              [c,o,b,a,l,t,o],
              [p,i,s,t,o,l,a],
              [s,t,a,t,a,l,e]].
```

You can of course easily obtain such an explicit (sometimes called **spatial**) representation automatically, using *all-solutions* predicates such as `findall/3`.

The key predicate I now introduce lets us relate a word in this representation to its *every second* letter:

```
word_evens([_,A,_,B,_,C,_], [A,B,C]).
```

Note how easily this relation can be expressed if you can reason explicitly about the list of letters that constitute a word.

Now, the whole solution, using the predicates `permutation/2` and `transpose/2`, which you can either find as library predicates in your Prolog system, or also implement easily yourself:

```
solution(Ls) :-
        Ls = [V1,V2,V3,H1,H2,H3],
        words(Ws),
        Ws = [First|_],
        maplist(same_length(First), Ls),
        maplist(word_evens, [H1,H2,H3], Ess),
        transpose(Ess, TEss),
        maplist(word_evens, [V1,V2,V3], TEss),
        permutation(Ws, Ls).
```

Sample query and the two solutions:

```
?- solution(Ls).
Ls = [[a, s, t, a, n, t, e], [c, o, b, a, l, t, o], [p, i, s, t, o, l|...], [a, s, t, o, r|...], [b, a, r, a|...], [s, t, a|...]] ;
Ls = [[a, s, t, o, r, i, a], [b, a, r, a, t, t, o], [s, t, a, t, a, l|...], [a, s, t, a, n|...], [c, o, b, a|...], [p, i, s|...]] ;
false.
```

At least `maplist/2` should be available in your Prolog, and `same_length/2` is easy to define if your system does not provide it.

If you really want to express disequality of terms, use **[prolog-dif](/questions/tagged/prolog-dif)**.

Comment: Thank you for confirming my feelings that this exercise came too early.  Also wanted to thank you for the heads up on (for me) future tools.  I went with a different response as "the" answer because it pointed out something that I had foolishly overlooked, which I now suspect was the point of the exercise.

Comment: You are very welcome! I only have one more observation: Even if you learn everything the book contains, you will not have the means to obtain *either* of the two solutions that are posted here. This is because essential predicates like `dif/2` and `call/N` are not included in it, and so you cannot implement `maplist/3` even if you read the book to the end.